# Ruby, DB2/400, ibm_db causing "segmentation fault"

Tags: ruby, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Ok, I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a DB2 database running on an AS/400 (iSeries, Power i, System i, whatever IBM is calling it these days).  Here are my specifics:

- OS: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
- Ruby: 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
- ibm_db: 2.5.9 x86-mingw32
- CLI db2level (32-bit): DB2 v9.7.0.441

I've been trying to find some simple documentation but IBM's information is pretty hard to follow.  I think I'm at the point where I should be able to run irb and enter "require 'mswin32/ibm_db'" but when I do I get this error:

```
C:\clidriver\bin>irb
Welcome to IRB. You are using ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]. Have fun ;)
>> require 'mswin32/ibm_db'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ibm_db-2.5.9-x86-mingw32/lib/mswin32/rb19x   /ibm_db.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------

...a bunch of stuff, let me know if I should include it or not...

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I haven't been able to find anything to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pablo

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled and reinstalled the ibm_db gem...same error.

Comment: It is rare enough to see a question with both the `python` and `ibm-midrange` tags.  I never thought I'd see one with both `ruby` and `ibm-midrange`!

Comment: Ha! In fact there is (as I am writing this) only one question each with those tag combos!

Comment: Well, if I keep having as much trouble as I've been having, there's likely be a lot more!

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to hope we see more such questions simply from the popularity of using the technologies together.

Comment: I agree.  Not a lot of info out there on this particular combo at the moment, hence my challenges.  Turns out this particular issue is a reproduceable bug in ibm_db with Ruby 1.9.3.  It works fine in 1.9.2.  I'll post a link to the RubyForge discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, as I said in my comment above, that the issue I was having was directly related to Ruby 1.9.3 and did not exist in Ruby 1.9.2.  [The RubyForge discussion explaining the issue](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=50618&forum_id=9503).  A fix is not available yet.